# GTA5 Get rid of Chop

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

I have inherited a dog and worked out how to stop him following me around but is there a way to get rid of him all together? I'm very house proud and don't want him messin up my yard when I have folks over.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Franklins dog, Chop, no you cannot get rid of him. You actually use him in a mission in the story missions.